# Text gets garbled after hibernate

Tags: display

My 12.04 install sometimes does this to the text on the screen:

[image]

[image]

This happens on all text in nautilus, all context menus, bookmarks/omnibox/statusbar on Chrome, and elsewhere in other programs. I've never had it happen to me after a clean boot, but it does sometimes happen after I boot from a hibernated OS.

I had recently installed Gnome Shell 3(unstable), but I removed it later, and this problem started then.

How ought I fix this?

Comment: You might have some of Gnome left over.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Seth: I ran the normal aptget purge/uninstall. That's it, I guess.

Comment: Please run "sudo apt-get autoremove"  and remove any packages it finds.

Comment: @Seth: That's also been done, repeatedly. I clear out the cache periodically.